# Properties of Open balls

Tags: general-topology

could you help me please with the properties of open disks in R^n.

I want to show that the family of all open disks in R^n has the ptoperties:

1. It covers R^n
2. (Chinese property). For each Dx1(E1), Dx2(E2) and for each x which belongs to the intersection of Dx1 and Dx2 there exists Dx3(E3) such that x belongs to Dx3 which is the subset of intersection of Dx1 and Dx2
   .

Comment: If you use non-standard notation like Dx1(E1), you really need to explain exactly what you mean by it.

Comment: See this related question: [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200070/determining-whether-a-basis-of-open-balls-is-a-basis)

Comment: HINT for 2: Try to draw a picture for yourself of the situation in $R^2$. What should the radius of $D_{x_3}(E_3)$ be for it to be contained in the intersection?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis This question is practially a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For every point in $x$ there is an open ball containing $x$, e.g., the ball with center $x$ and radius $\delta>0$ (denoted $B_\delta(x)$ below).
2. I paraphrase the answer by Alex Becker [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/200072/79365). Suppose two open balls $B_{\delta}(x)$ and $B_{\delta'}(y)$ intersect, and $z\in B_{\delta}(x)\cap B_{\delta'}(y)$. Then $d(z,x)<\delta$ and $d(z,y)<\delta'$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be smaller than $d(z,x)-\delta$ and $d(z,y)-\delta'$. It follows that $B_{\epsilon,n}(z)\subset B_{\delta,n}(x)\cap B_{\delta',n}(y)$